# django-admin.py launches IDE

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I just went to create a new django project and I typed django-admin.py startproject my_project into the command prompt and it opened the django-admin.py file in my ide (komodo edit).

This happens every time I run this command in any form, even if I just try django-admin.py.  Any ideas what's going on and how I fix it?

I'm on Win Xp with django 1.2.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you associated .py files with Komodo Edit instead of with python.exe.   The simplest workaround is to type "python django-admin.py ..." to execute the admin.

You can look in your Explorer options to change the association.  There's a right-click menu option I think called "Open With..." that will let you change it.

Comment: Didn't think about that.  I made my python files open in komodo upon double clicking them so I could save a little time.  Didn't think about it having this effect though.  Thanks